# GROUP BY repite registros al presentarlo en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, mssql, azure-sql

Hola soy un poco nuevo en SQL SERVER, no se si es la manera correcta de hacer ejercicio, por favor ayudenme :(

Si no coloco el GROUP BY, me generaria ese COUNT como en 25 filas, redundando la misma informacion una y otra vez.

```
-- 4. Consultar la cantidad de clientes por genero.
CREATE VIEW CONSULTA4 WITH ENCRYPTION AS
    SELECT
        (
            SELECT COUNT(CLIENTE.GENERO)
            FROM LUBRICADORA.dbo.CLIENTE CLIENTE
            WHERE CLIENTE.GENERO = 1
            GROUP BY CLIENTE.GENERO
        ) AS 'Cantidad Hombres',
        (
            SELECT COUNT(CLIENTE.GENERO)
            FROM LUBRICADORA.dbo.CLIENTE CLIENTE
            WHERE CLIENTE.GENERO = 0
            GROUP BY CLIENTE.GENERO
        ) AS 'Cantidad Mujeres'
    FROM LUBRICADORA.dbo.CLIENTE CLIENTE
    GROUP BY CLIENTE.GENERO;
```

No se si existe otra manera de presentar en dos columnas separadas con sus respectivas condiciones cada una para calcular el total de hombres y el total de mujeres por separado y en una sola vista.

El problema esta al mostrar esto en una vista:
[image: ERROR SQL SERVER GROUP BY]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es neceario realizar subconsultas para obtener un `count`

```
Create table dbo.Cliente (idcliente int, nombre varchar(100), Genero tinyint);
Go

Insert into dbo.Cliente (idcliente, nombre, genero)
values
(1,'Ana',2),
(2,'Bea',2),
(3,'Adolfo',1),
(4,'Luisa',2),
(5,'Pedro',1);

GO
```

Puedes realizar un `case` condicionando la función `count`

```
CREATE VIEW CONSULTA4 WITH ENCRYPTION AS
         SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CLIENTE.GENERO = 1 THEN 1 END) 
                    AS  'Cantidad Hombres',
                COUNT(CASE WHEN CLIENTE.GENERO = 2 THEN 1 END) 
                    AS 'Cantidad Mujeres'
        FROM LUBRICADORA.dbo.CLIENTE CLIENTE;
GO
```

[image: Result]

Comment: En el enlace puedes ver, el motivo por el que te devuelve 25 filas [Group by como funciona](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/group-by-quizas-la-clausula-mas-conflictiva/)

Comment: Wow amigo eres un grande, muchas gracias, ayer estuve pensando tanto en esta consulta. Gracias men.